# wordpress wp_nav_menu exlude categories

Tags: wordpress, categories

I want to exclude the "uncategorized" category from my main menu. The menu is being generated by the wp_nav_menu() function.

I've searched the web, but keep being led to excluding pages using something similar to this

`wp_list_pages(exclude=1,2,3)`

function, but that is not the function that my header menu is being generated from?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add custom menus. Follow these steps:

1. Go to Appearance > Menus.
2. On the right side, you will see a form for adding new menu. Enter a
   menu name; say "menu-1" and click on "Create Menu" button.
3. Inside "Theme Locations" section, choose your menu from "Primary
   Menu" dropdown list and click on "Save".
4. Next, scroll down to "Pages" section and select the pages you wish
   to show on menu. Click on "Add to Menu" button. These pages will now
   appear on the right side. (You can also add categories to this menu.)
5. Finally, click on "Save Menu" button. Your primary menu is created.